# Why would some one define a pointer like this?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, compound-literals

```
const char** list_entry[] = 
{
    (const char*[]){"ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4"},
    (const char*[]){"ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4"}
};
```

I don't quite understand as I could not think of anything I couldn't accomplish with only one "*" instead of 2.

What are the primary concerns/advantages for doing things like this?

Comment: No temporary variables are needed here. If you think you can do better then edit your improvement into the question, check it compiles in standard mode, and we will critique it . (This pattern works if the strings might all be different lengths)

Comment: @M.M the thing is I think using both one "*" and 2 are virtually the same, mine isn't better, just I failed to see the point of using 2 " * "s. I'm worried about what I'm missing.

Comment: This is like a two-dimensional array of strings. (Actually an array of pointers into arrays of strings.) If you declared `const char* list_entry[];` then `list_entry[1][2]` would have type `const char`. As it is, `list_entry[1][2]` has type `const char*`, which is good since it's a pointer to the second `"ent3"` string.

Answer (score 2):

In this declaration

```
const char** list_entry[] = 
{
    (const char*[]){"ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4"},
    (const char*[]){"ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4"}
};
```

there are used two compound ;literals

```
    (const char*[]){"ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4"},
    (const char*[]){"ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4"}
```

that have either the automatic or static storage duration depending on where the declaration occurs.

Without the compound literals you would need to define two separate named arrays of pointers to string literals and then declare `list_entry` using these named arrays.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows two alternative approaches of defining the array `list_entry` with using compound literals and without using compound literals.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
{   
    const char** list_entry[] =     
    {
        (const char*[]){ "ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4", "" },
        (const char*[]){ "ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4", "" }
    };

    size_t N = sizeof( list_entry ) / sizeof( *list_entry );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; list_entry[i][j][0] != '\0'; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%s ", list_entry[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

    putchar( '\n' );

{
    const char *list1[] = { "ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4", "" };
    const char *list2[] = { "ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4", "" };

    const char** list_entry[] = { list1, list2 };   

    size_t N = sizeof( list_entry ) / sizeof( *list_entry );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; list_entry[i][j][0] != '\0'; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%s ", list_entry[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
ent1 ent2 ent3 ent4 
ent1 ent2 ent3 ent4 

ent1 ent2 ent3 ent4 
ent1 ent2 ent3 ent4
```

From the second code snippet it is clear that for example the array `list1`

```
const char *list1[] = { "ent1", "ent2", "ent3", "ent4", "" };
```

is an array of pointers to first character of string literals. (Note: array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements. And string literals are character arrays.)

This array of pointers used as an initializer in the declaration of `list_entry`

```
const char** list_entry[] = { list1, list2 };
```

is also converted to pointer to its first element. So as the element that is list1 has the type `const char *` then pointer to its first element will have the type  `const char **`.

Comment: Hello, I get what you meant. But if the primary concern is for accessing, for example a single letter/character of a char array, then "**" isn't really necessary? It is also doable with only 1 "*"? I have successfully done it.

Comment: Hello, I just figured out. Using 2 "*"s is much more intuitive, using only 1 "*" requires a lot of brain gymnastics and are prone to errors.

Comment: @user3577050 If you have an array of the type T like T a[] then *a gives the first element of the array. So *list_entry gives an object of the type const char ** that is the first element of the array (pointer to the first string literal).  To get the first character of the first string literal you have to write ***list_entry.